# "Allowed memory exhausted" error reading Filemaker data with laravel

Tags: laravel, filemaker

I am using this package to connect and read data from Filemaker:https://github.com/andreossido/laravel-filemaker

Environment: Windows Server 2019 with a 64bit DSN ODBC

When I try to get data with:

```
$data = DB::connection('connection_name')->select('SELECT field FROM table')->get();
```

I receive this error:

> "Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
> 1580547964929 bytes)"

in this file vendor\abram\laravel-odbc\src\ODBCPdoStatement.php

```
$this->statement = odbc_prepare($conn, $this->query);
```

Do you have any suggestion to solve?

In php.ini I only have `extension=php_odbc.dll`, do I need to add `extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll`?

Comment: This error related to memory limit in php config. First check to see if it is possible to load less data (There might be a way to reduce memory usage in your code). If not, you can always change memory limit on your php.ini. Edit php.ini file and change `memory_limit=x` where x is whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for reply, looking at the huge number of bytes laravel is trying to allocate I think there's something else to fix, my controller contains just 1 line of code and the table contains 1 text field and 1 record

Comment: Change your query to `DB::connection('connection_name')->table('table_name')->select('field')->get()`.

Comment: Same error.
I tried also this removing "->get()" and adding dd() and I got:
`Builder {#914 ▼
  +connection: ODBCConnection {#911 ▼
    #pdo: ODBCPdo {#910 ▼
      ⚠: ThrowingCasterException {#955 ▼
        #message: "Unexpected ErrorException thrown from a caster: PDO::getAttribute(): SQLSTATE[00000]: No error: PDO constructor was not called"
     ...
`